# How to reuse a SimpleDateFormat class object in java to get different formatted answer

Tags: java, date, calendar, simpledateformat

We have a `Calendar` class object:

```
Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
```

And we have a `SimpleDateFormat` object which is formatted like below:

```
SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd");
String longDate = dateFormat.format(calendar.getTime());
```

So we get the current date in `longDate`. Now I want to get the current year, but I want to reuse the `dateFormat` object. Is there any way to do it? I know I can **initially** format the class like:

```
SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-yy");
```

and then get the results from the resultant string, but I want to reuse the `dateFormat` object to get the year results.

Comment: Why? If you’re after a memory reduction, I think this is the wrong place to invest your effort. That aside, the `SimpleDateFormat` and `Calendar` classes are long outdated, you shouldn’t use them at all. I recommend like `DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd");` and then `ZonedDateTime.now(ZoneId.of("America/Araguaina")).format(formatter)`.

Comment: I am a newbie in programming and because i was using a online tutorial to learn the basics, i was using a outdated class. Thanks for pointing it out and also thanks for the recommendation. I will check them out.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Well you *can* use `applyPattern`:

```
SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd");
System.out.println(dateFormat.format(new Date()); // 16
dateFormat.applyPattern("dd-yy");
System.out.println(dateFormat.format(new Date()); // 16-18
```

However, I would personally *strongly* recommend that you not use these types at all, preferring the `java.time` types. I'd also recommend against using 2-digit years.

Answer (score 3):

As you have a Calendar Object already, why not just call its [get](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html#get(int)) method

```
int day = calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
```